# .Net Maui Including large file in project

Tags: c#, file, build, maui, buildaction

I am trying to include a large file in my project but it doesn't let me. If set the Build Action to "MauiAsset" I get the following error: "APT2000 filemap E 08-18 15:25:19 23420  8832 MapViewOfFile(0, 3487748096) failed with error 8 "filemap E 08-18 15:25:19 23420  8832 MapViewOfFile(0, 3487748096) failed with error 8".

With a little bit of research I found out that the maximum size of files you can include as MauiAsset is about 3GB, this file happens to be around 3.5GB.

I have tried setting Build Action to "Embedded Resource" but this gives me the following error: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.'

Which after a little Googling I found out also has to do with the size of the file.

So basically my question is: How do I include files that are 4GB or larger?

Comment: what platforms do you need to support?  What exactly is in this file?

Comment: Platform is Android, the file is a mbtile. Basically stored to have a working offline map.

Comment: Are you expecting the end result to be 4+ GB apk file?

Comment: I mean obviously not useful on a phone, but this is not meant for on a phone, I have a android device with 1TB ssd space. I am just wanting to know if there is a way around the current limit of 3GB.

Comment: According to the APK Expansion Files, Google Play requires that the compressed APK that users download be no more than 100MB. If you want to add the "big files" to the application, you can try to download the file after the app is installed.